# Code block passed to each works with brackets but not with 'do'-'end' (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I recently started learning ruby, and I understood that you coud use code blocks with both of these syntaxes. But I just found a case which I dont understand:

```
#my_hash is a hash in which the keys are strings and the values arrays, but dont think about the specifics fo the code

#if I run my code like this, it works perfectly

my_hash.each do |art|
  puts mystring.gsub(art[0]).each {
    art[1][rand(art[1].length) -1]
  }
end

#but if I use this, it prints "Enumerator"

my_hash.each do |art|
  puts mystring.gsub(art[0]).each do
    art[1][rand(art[1].length) -1]
  end
end
```

Is it because you cant nest do-end pairs? 
I am using 1.9

Comment: Not an answer, but I noticed you can simplify your hash iterator by using the `|k,v|` form.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/) and [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
puts mystring.gsub(art[0]).each do
  art[1][rand(art[1].length) -1]
end
```

Here you called `puts` without parens, the `do ... end` refers to the `puts` method, that does nothing with a block and prints `mystring.gsub(art[0]).each` (with is a `Enumerator`).

The `{ ... }` is called with the nearest method. Becomes ugly, but you can do it with `do ... end`:

```
puts(mystring.gsub(art[0]).each do
  art[1][rand(art[1].length) -1]
end)
```

Or, better, put the result in a variable and print the variable:

```
var = mystring.gsub(art[0]).each do
  art[1][rand(art[1].length) -1]
end
puts var
```

Anyway, the `each` don't changes the object, it just iterate and returns the object itself. You may be wanting the `map` method, test it.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. In my case I am able to modify the object to .each, but I guess that is because I am using it with gsub, right?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Scott's reply, and quoting [Jim Weirich](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc#comment-27196725):

> The difference is where in the operator precedence table they fall. { } binds tighter than do/end. For example:
>
> f g { }
>
> is parsed as f(g { }), where the braces belong to the method g. On the other hand,
>
> f g do end
>
> is parsed as f(g) do end, where the braces belong to the method f. It only matters when you omit parenthesis and create ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting do/end pairs is perfectly legal in Ruby, but you are coming up against a subtle precedence issue between { } and do/end.

You can read a little more about that [here](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc).