# Pass block into define_method

Tags: ruby, memoization

## The Problem

There is a pattern that I find myself to be frequently using, so I'd like to dry it up. I have stuff like this:

```
class InfoGatherer
  def foo
    true
  end

  def people
    unless @people
      @people = # Long and complex calculation (using foo)
    end
    @people
  end
end
```

I'd like to dry this up to look like this:

```
class InfoGatherer
  extend AttrCalculator

  def foo
    true
  end

  attr_calculator(:people) { # Long and complex calculation (using foo) }
end
```

To accomplish this, I defined a module `AttrCalculator` to extend into `InfoGatherer`. Here's what I tried:

```
module AttrCalculator
  def attr_calculator(variable_name_symbol)
    variable_name = "@#{variable_name_symbol}"

    define_method variable_name_symbol do
      unless instance_variable_defined?(variable_name)
        instance_variable_set(variable_name, block.call)
      end
      instance_variable_get(variable_name)
    end

  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I try something as simple as `InfoGatherer.new.people`, I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for InfoGatherer:Class
```

Well, that's odd. Why is `block` running in the scope of `InfoGatherer:Class`, rather than its instance `InfoGatherer.new`?

## The Research

I know I can't use `yield`, because that would try to catch the wrong block, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306731/using-yield-inside-define-method-in-ruby).
I attempted to use `self.instance_exec(block)` in the place of `block.call` above, but then I received a new error:

```
LocalJumpError: no block given
```

Huh? I see the same error in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718340/code-block-passed-to-each-works-with-brackets-but-not-with-do-end-ruby), but I'm already using bracket notation, so the answers there don't seem to apply.

I also tried to use `class_eval`, but I'm not sure how to call `block` inside of a string. This certainly doesn't work:

```
class_eval("
  def #{variable_name_symbol}
    unless #{variable_name}
      #{variable_name} = #{block.call}
    end
    #{variable_name}
  end
")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That use case is called memoization. It can be done easily like:

```
def people
  @people ||= # Long and complex calculation (using foo)
end
```

You shouldn't go into the mess like you are.

Comment: That's what I do when it's a short and simple calculation. :) But you're right; any complex calculation can be moved into a helper method, and easily placed on one line. I'm still curious about what the proper way to pass a block into `define_method` is, though. Even if my provided use-case isn't a solid one.

Comment: It does not have to be in one line. If you have a long chunk of code, you can do `||= begin ... end`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the last persons

```
def people(varariable = nil)
  @people ||= ComplexCalculation.new(variable).evaluate
end

class ComplexCalculation

  def initialize(variable)
    @variable = variable
  end

  def evaluate(variable)
    #stuff
  end

end
```

By extracting this class you are isolating that complexity and will have a much better experience.

Comment: That's good to point that out as option, but it's just one of many, including `@people ||= my_method(variable)`.  btw, I think you meant `def people(variable=nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, inside the `define_method`, `self` was surprisingly `InfoGatherer`, rather than an *instance* of `InfoGatherer`. So I was on the right track with `self.instance_exec(block)`.

The working solution is `self.instance_exec(&block)` (note the ampersand). I guess the interpreter doesn't recognize that `block` is a block unless you label it as such? If anyone can explain this better than me, please do.

As a side note, this is *not* the best way to solve this particular problem. See @sawa's answer for a clean way to memoize complicated calculations.